# Warning: Multiple copy constructors defined while deleting them

Tags: c++, c++11

Environment: VS2015 Update 3, 64 bit (debug|release) compile

In the code below, if I uncomment the `Maybe(X&) = delete` line, I get the warning mentioned in the code below and in the title of the question.

Now, I am aware, that there are certain rules in C++(11?), which might render
the explicit deletion of that constructor obsolete. Only, even after searching
the web for a while, I could not find a definite rule, which would confirm, that 
if I only delete `Maybe(const X&) = delete`, the compiler will not auto generate the other copy constructor.

So my question is first and foremost:
Can anyone point me to spot in the C++ specification, which clearly defines the 
rules for auto generation of copy constructors? Alternatively, some less official 
easy to remember rule of thumb on how to be certain of what will happen would also be welcome.

```
template <class X>
class Maybe
{
    X *m_just;
public:
    explicit Maybe(const X& x)
        : m_just(new X(x))
    {}
    Maybe()
        : m_just(nullptr)
    {}
    Maybe(const Maybe<X>&& other)
        : m_just(other.m_just)
    {
        other.m_just = nullptr;
    }
    Maybe(const Maybe<X>&) = delete;
    // If line below is uncommented, this produces the warning: 
    // warning C4521: 'Maybe<Int32>': multiple copy constructors specified
    // Maybe(Maybe<X>&) = delete; 

    ~Maybe()
    {
        delete m_just;
        m_just = nullptr;
    }
    // ... more members and code which are not related to question
    // ...
};
```

Please do not comment on the whole idea of that class. It is just private tinkering in my private lab... ;)

Comment: [here](https://blog.feabhas.com/2015/11/becoming-a-rule-of-zero-hero/)'s a pretty great [chart](https://i0.wp.com/blog.feabhas.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Slide12.jpg?w=995)

Comment: My intention is to absolutely and really totally DO NOT. As in - I want none of the auto generated copy constructors. Did not start with the assignment operators yet...

Comment: `Maybe` and `Maybe<X>` is the same thing, due to an arcane but useful mechanism called "Injection".

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes - I changed it to ``Maybe<X>`` once that warning showed up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will only generate one of `Maybe(Maybe<X>&)` and `Maybe(const Maybe<X>&)`.
The conditions for the choice are listed in section 12.8, paragraph 8:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class `X` will have the
>   form `X::X(const X&)` if
>
> - each direct or virtual base class `B` of `X` has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type `const B&` or `const volatile B&`, and
> - for all the non-static data members of `X` that are of a `class type M` (or array thereof), each such class type has a copy constructor whose
>     first parameter is of type `const M&` or `const volatile M&`
>
> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy constructor will have the form
>   `X::X(X&)`

Or more informally, the parameter will be `const` if and only if everything that needs to be copied can be "const-copied".

Deleting one will not cause the other to be generated.

Since you have no base class and your only member is a pointer, the generated constructor will be of the const variety and you can leave out the line causing an error.

Comment: I tried your test advice you gave towards the end of your answer. It does not seem to matter if I delete the ``Maybe(const X&)`` or the ``Maybe(X&)`` copy constructor. Compiles both times and so that would mean... that none of both is being generated in my current code?

Comment: @BitTickler That bit's probably wrong, then, or at least unreliable.  It could also be that the compiler is a bit wonky, but since I'm not sure I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

My C++ is a little bit rusty so this might be wrong, but I don't think you should even have a non-const copy constructor (except for the move constructor naturally).

If `a = b` changes `b` you're going to surprise some people. Perhaps it's legitimate for the copy constructor to change the source in a way that's not externally visible, but in that case I think you're better off using `const_cast` inside the const copy constructor.

The error I don't think is about `delete`, it's about defining multiple copy constructors, which isn't allowed. I suspect even allowing the non-const copy constructor is a bit of a wart in the language.

Comment: I am tempted to think you refer mostly to my move constructor, which is not a copy constructor (at least in my eyes). But yes, I agree it is funny that I can mutate the const object in my move constructor without warning and error ;)

Comment: No the move constructor is fine, I'm not talking about that. It's the second copy constructor you get when you uncomment that line that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
other.m_just = nullptr;
```

This line should not compile. Something must be wrong with your compiler, or your code example doesn't exactly reflect what you're compiling.

Anyway, the move constructor should take a *non-const* rvalue reference.

The commented line is simply not necessary. Just leave it out. If you define the copy constructor (even as deleted), no other form of the copy constructor is defined by the compiler, ever, so if you leave the line out, there simply is no constructor that takes a non-const reference to Self, meaning that overload resolution will just pick the const reference copy constructor, which is deleted anyway.

Comment: I kept the move constructor code for some giggles. It compiles (and runs) without warning and error with my compiler (gave my tool chain in the top of my question). Maybe I should have deleted it to keep people from being distracted.

Comment: @BitTickler Ah, I get it now. It's a member function of a template class, and thus the compiler won't ever type-check it unless it is instantiated. (MSVC is extremely lazy about checking templates.) If you actually attempt to move-construct a `Maybe`, you *will* get the error. (Tested with Update 2, don't have U3 installed yet.)

Comment: Actually, if I comment out my move constructor, my code does not compile. Yet, if I set a breakpoint at the mutating statement inside, it never gets hit... Now, who can explain that?! :) Without move constructor it tries to use the copy constructor: 1>...\usingclangmaybe.cpp(225): error C2280: 'Maybe<Int32>::Maybe(Maybe<Int32> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>  ...\usingclangmaybe\usingclangmaybe\usingclangmaybe.cpp(64): note: see declaration of 'Maybe<Int32>::Maybe'